# use java to create file in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, imacros

First of all I am iMacros scripts writer. 
This is java function for writing a file (not fully complete but you will get the idea)

```
 bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

            //Start writing to the output stream
            bufferedWriter.write("Writing line one to file");
```

Now bellow is java function used in JavaScript to do the same task as the function above and I run that .js file in iMacros. Works like a charm.

```
//Function to write the file
function writeFile(filename, data)
{
   try
   { 

      //write the data

      out = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(filename, true));
      out.newLine();
      out.write(data);
      out.close();
      out=null;
   }
   catch(e)   //catch and report any errors
   {
      alert(""+e);
   }
}
```

Now I need a java function that will create file and folder on Hard Drive location and I found this.

package com.mkyong.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

```
public class CreateFileExample 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {   
        try {

          File file = new File("c:\\newfile.txt");

          if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

But now I need java function that will create folder and an empty file (with different extensions like .txt .csv etc.) and the function will work in JavaScript.

Can anyone give me some guide lines from the two examples above? How can I write a functions in Java and run it in JavaScript?

Comment: File has a method [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) that will create missing subdirectories but I doubt that's not going to help you a lot.  Despite similar names Java and Javascript are two entirely different languages, mostly living in different environments.  You need to clarify what you need, I am especially confused by `Now bellow is java function used in JavaScript to do the same task as the function above and I run that .js file in iMacros. Works like a charm.` which seems to suggest you somehow already call Java from javascript???

Comment: "which seems to suggest you somehow already call Java from javascript??? " YES!

Since JavaScript can't write in files I use Java and call it in JavaScript to write file. So above you have Java method called in JavaScript to open and write text in file. So I gave an example how i use Java in JavaScript file and press Play to do the job in iMacros. So from that example I need function in that creates folder and file in that folder. You understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is used in iMacros .js file. It is a Java method called in JavaScript.

```
createFile("C:\\testingfolder","test.csv");

function createFile(folder,file)
{

destinationDir = new java.io.File(folder).mkdirs();
file = new java.io.File(folder,file);
file.createNewFile();
}
```

The function creates folder and in it creates a file.

Answer (score 2):

I won't claim to fully understand the question, but this is how to make sure some directory exists, and to create a random file in it:

```
// make the dir and ensure the entire path exists
File destinationDir = new File("c:\\whereever\you\want\that\file\to\land").mkdirs();
// make some file in that directory
File file = new File(destinationDir,"whateverfilename.whateverextension");
// continue with your code
if (file.createNewFile()){
    System.out.println("File is created!");
}else{
    System.out.println("File already exists.");
}
```

Comment: I used your example and wrote this 
destinationDir = new java.io.File("c:\\testingfolder").mkdirs();
And it worked! I created a new folder but when I wrote this
file = new java.io.File(destinationDir,"test.csv");  it didn't create new file in that folder...
And when I wrote this file.createNewFile();  I got an error. 
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified (Error code: 991)


Almost there!

Comment: I found a solution. Man you helped me a lot. For real. I will write a solution here so if anyone needs it they can use it.